# Jetpack Navigation Component: Update Bottom Nav Bar on Deep Links

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am testing out the Navigation Component in a sample app. I have a bottom navigation bar with three fragments; say A, B and C. Further, C has another flow connected to it which goes like this; C -> C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C. No nested graphs in the xml-definition. See image. I have also hooked up the bottom bar according to the documentation.

When running the app and moving around in the app everything works fine, the bottom bar updates the selected item.

However, when adding a deep link to open C2, the app opens C2 but in the bottom bar A is still selected. What am I missing? Should there be any actions connecting A, B and C?

[image]

Comment: have you writtern something like this:  `navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener{}` ?

Comment: No, I haven't. According to the docs it should listen for changes by default. And it does! Until I go to a destination using a deep link..

Comment: I found this article saying that there are some bugs regarding deep linking and back behavior: https://android.jlelse.eu/breeze-deep-links-with-android-architecture-components-navigation-98cc8da83928 (See "But there are few rotten apples", second item)

Comment: hmmmm, Have you added A, B and C as Top level destinations?

Comment: Yes, top level destinations. So I was wondering if there should be any global actions to them to somehow connect everything? What do you think?

Comment: I'm not risking further, I don't know

Comment: Can you try deep linking to parent C and when the control lands there , you can further take it to C1 based on arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and I was able to fix it by nesting my nav graphs. In your case, I would take fragments C, C1, C2, C3 and put them in their own navigation graph nested within the main one. Android's Navigation component will then pick this up, see the `startDestination` of that graph (which you would make as C I'm guessing) and change the bottom navigation accordingly.

This worked for me and has been the only solution that worked for me so far. I believe the integration between notifications (I'm using the `NavDeepLinkBuilder`) and the Navigation component is still very new so many features and options are missing.